# session lose using cross domain in angular js and codeingiter

Tags: angularjs, angular, codeigniter

I have two domains:

http://localhost:9000 / My AngularJS App created with Yeoman.
http://localhost/ My PHP app created with CodeIgniter.
My Angular app does `$http.post` to authenticate in the PHP app and save a session to identify the user as logged, but, when I try recovery the user information stored in the CI Session, just don't exist.

How can I allow the AngularJS app access the session and don't lose?

Answer (score 0):

what about `SessionStorage / LocalStorage / window.SessionStorage / window.LocalStorage ?` you can store your session here